# chrome debugger doesn't show JWT response body

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, jwt

I have two computers where I work on my JS SPA app, desktop and laptop. I changed my api to require JWT for security (headers have Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and what not) and on my laptop the Chrome debugger stopped showing the response body. It shows the first call to the API where it makes the initial request to verify the headers, but it doesn't show the 2nd request which gets the json response from the server. So it's very difficult to debug on my laptop b/c I never know what is being returned from the server without setting breakpoints in my code.

On my desktop it shows both the initial access check and then the follow up json body and it shows the two calls on separate lines. My desktop is version 56.xxx and my laptop was older. So I updated the laptop to version 59.xxx and it's still happening on my laptop. I'm afraid to upgrade Chrome on my desktop b/c I'm worried it will stop showing the json body response and I really need this for debugging.

This must be a Chrome setting the I made by mistake? I don't know.

Thanks.

Comment: If both requests use the same method, and the request is actually made, and you didn't apply filtering in network panel then it's a bug, see if there's a report on https://crbug.com or submit a new one.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's a bug b/c it works on my desktop. I probably applied filtering on my laptop somehow and didn't realize it. Is there a way to reset the filter back to nothing?